# Inserting Node into a Linked List

Tags: python

I want to create a function that inserts a node into any place in a linked list.
There is a test function to test if the function works. My problem is that when I run the test function none of the outputs show, any ideas?

```
"""
Creates and returns a linked list containing all of the elements
of the Python-style list parameter.
"""

def createList(plist):
    myList = None
    # goes backwards, adding each element to the beginning
    # of the list.  
    for index in range(len(plist)-1, -1, -1):
        myList = insertValueHead(myList, plist[index])
    return myList

'''
Creates a string representation of the values in the linked list such as:
5->6->9->14.
'''

def listString(myList):
    ptr = myList
    str1 = ''
    while ptr != None:
    str1 += str(ptr['data'])
    ptr = ptr['next']
    if ptr != None:
      str1 += "->"
    str1 = str1
    return str1

'''
Inserts a new node containing the value "value" to the head of the list.
LinkedList is the head of the list to be added to
Value is the data to be stored in the node'''


def insertValueHead(myList, value):
    newnode = {}
    newnode["data"] = value
    #set the next pointer of this new node to the head of the list, linkedList
    #newnode is now the head of the list 
    newnode["next"] = myList
    return newnode


def insertNode(myList, index, value):
    if index == 0:
        newnode = {}
        newnode["data"] = value
        newnode["next"] = myList

    elif index > 0:
        newnode = {}
        newnode["data"] = value
        ptr = myList
        count = 0
        while ptr != None and count < index-1:
            ptr = ptr['next']
            print count
            count += 1
        return ptr
        newnode['next'] = ptr['next']
        ptr['next'] = newnode

def testInsert():
    #test code to ensure that insertNode is working correctly.
    myList = createList([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    print "The initial list", listString(myList)
    #insert 0 at the head
    myList = insertNode(myList,0, 0)
    print "Inserted 0 at the start of list: ", listString(myList)
    #insert 7 at the end
    myList = insertNode(myList, 7, 7)
    print "Inserted 7 at the end of list: ", listString(myList)
    myList= insertNode(myList, 3, 2.2)
    print "Inserted 2.2 in the 3rd position: ", listString(myList)
    myList = insertNode(myList, 26, 12)   #should generate an error

testInsert()
```

Comment: You'll have to fix the indentation in the `listString` function yourself; as it is presented here now it is not valid Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `insertNode()` function never returns `newnode` when inserting at index 0. As such, `None` is returned instead.

Since that's the first operation that the `testInsert()` function does after building the initial linked list, `myList` in that function is now `None` and the rest of the test is invalid.

For the `index > 0` case, your `return` statement comes too early; you return `ptr`, e.g. the node at `index - 1` before inserting the new value. All statements after that `return` statement are not executed.

You don't need to special-case the `index = 0` case, really. Here is a better version:

```
def insertNode(myList, index, value):
    newnode = {'data': value, 'next': None}
    retval = myList if index else newnode 
    prev, ptr = None, myList
    while ptr is not None and index > 0:
        prev, ptr = ptr, ptr['next']
        index -= 1
    if index > 0:
        raise ValueError('Index out of range')
    newnode['next'] = ptr
    if prev is not None:
        prev['next'] = newnode
    return retval
```

This version actually raises an error if you try to insert a value past the end; `index` will be greater than 0 in that case.

Comment: one more thing could you explain line 3 to me it's kind of confusing the one where you pronounce retval = myList

Comment: @H.H.: that's a conditional expression. You need to return the altered list, and either the new node is the first node in the linked list, or the original list is. That depends on the value of `index`; if it is not 0 we return `myList` at the end of the function, otherwise we return `newnode` at the end.

Comment: Ah I just had one more question, this code, mainly the while statements index part is set so it only works for this size of list, how would I make it more general. So that all it would do the same as asked in the test case but with any size list

Comment: @H.H.: not sure what you mean; this code works for any size of linked list *already*. The `index` merely determines where we insert the new node.

Comment: ah that was my bad! I am testing out a code that does something slightly different but is very similar to this and the error is somewhere in there! sorry for the trouble and again thank you! it'

Answer (score 1):

This code is unreachable:

```
    return ptr
    newnode['next'] = ptr['next'] # unreachable after a returnn statement
    ptr['next'] = newnode
```

Try moving the code inside the while loop and before you return:

```
    elif index > 0:
        newnode = {}
        newnode["data"] = value
        ptr = myList
        count = 0
        while ptr != None and count < index-1:
            ptr = ptr['next']
            print count
            count += 1
        newnode['next'] = ptr['next']
        ptr['next'] = newnode
        return ptr
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want those two lines of code to be outside the loop, not inside. It does need to be above the `return` though. Just unindent the lines from this answer by one level and it should work as intended.

Comment: I have now. My point is that your code is incorrect. Indenting those two line destroys the existing list as you loop over it. There are other errors though that probably prevent you from noticing (for instance, returning `ptr` rather than `myList` makes the head of the list get forgotten anyway).

Comment: @Blckknght, I noticed well.  There are a few issues in the code, the biggest was trying to access the code after the return statement and the answer to  the question which was why there  was not output